# Weird issue of iframe and border radius in firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, css

I faced a very weird issue of iframe and border radius in firefox.

Corners of button with border-radius we getting squared after over lapping on iframe.

jsfiddle as both demo of issue as well as solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/R4b5h/3/ here is the demo.

Solution for this is to add

```
sandbox="allow-scripts  allow-same-origin"
```

in iframe.